# Complex Analysis Solution to the Basel Problem ($\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, pi

Most of us are aware of the famous "Basel Problem":

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

I remember reading an elegant proof for this using complex numbers to help find the value of the sum.  I tried finding it again to no avail.  Does anyone know a complex number proof for the solution of the Basel Problem?

Comment: Any textbook in complex analysis has at least one proof written out or presented as an exercise.

Comment: @zyx I only have "Complex Variables and Applications, Second Edition" by Ruel Churchill.  Its about 40 years old now.  It contains no proof.

Comment: That's surprising, I was thinking of Churchill with its computational style of problems as exactly the kind of book that would have it.

Comment: @Argon: I don't know about the second edition, but exercise 14 in section 57 of the fifth edition has an equivalent result (alternating sum = $\pi^2/12$).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most straightforward way I know is to consider the contour integral
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\pi\cot(\pi z)\frac{1}{z^2}\mathrm{d}z\tag{1}
$$
around circles whose radii are $\frac12$ off an integer.

The function $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ has residue $1$ at every integer.  Thus the integral in $(1)$ equals the residue of $\pi\cot(\pi z)\dfrac{1}{z^2}$ at $z=0$ plus twice the sum in question (one for the positive integers and one for the negative integers).

The integral in $(1)$ tends to $\color{blue}{0}$ as the radius goes to $\infty$.

The Laurent expansion of $\pi\cot(\pi z)\dfrac{1}{z^2}$ at $z=0$ is
$$
\frac{1}{z^3}-\frac{\pi^2}{3z}-\frac{\pi^4z}{45}-\frac{2\pi^6z^3}{945}-\dots\tag{2}
$$
The only term that contributes to the residue at $z=0$ is the $\dfrac1z$ term. That is, the residue at $z=0$ of $(2)$ is $\color{green}{-\frac{\pi^2}{3}}$. Thus, the sum in question must be $\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}$ (so that $\color{green}{-\frac{\pi^2}{3}}+2\cdot\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}=\color{blue}{0}$).

Answer (score 6):

All the proofs I know of are in [Kalman's article](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph116A/Sixways.pdf). There is one that uses complex analysis (residues, to be concrete).

Comment: Yes I liked that proof in Kalman's article, but there is also one in Robin Chapman's list of proofs.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that:

$\\ \displaystyle csc^2(\pi z)=\frac{1}{sin^2(\pi z)}=\frac{1}{4sin^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)cos^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}=\frac{sin^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)+cos^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}{4sin^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)cos^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{cos^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}+\frac{1}{sin^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(sec^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\right)= \frac{1}{4}\left(csc^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(csc^2\left(\frac{ (z-1)\pi}{2}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\right) \\ \\$

We conclude:

\begin{equation}
     csc^2(\pi z)=\frac{1}{4}\left(csc^2\left(\frac{ (z-1)\pi}{2}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\right) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Take z=1/4, we get:

\begin{equation}
    2=\frac{1}{4}\left(csc^2\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{\pi }{8}\right)\right) \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Let (2) our induction base, such as induction hypothesis valid for suppose that an n

\begin{equation}
    1=\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

Applying (1) in (3) , we have:
\begin{equation}
    1=\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}=\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\frac{1}{4}\left(csc^2\left(\frac{ \left(\frac{(2k+1)}{2^{n+1}}-1\right)\pi}{2}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{ \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}}{2}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    =\frac{2}{4^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\left(csc^2\left(\frac{(2k+1-2^{n+1})\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)+csc^2\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)\right)=
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    =\frac{2}{4^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\left(\frac{2^{n+1}-(2k+1))\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)+\frac{2}{4^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    =\frac{2}{4^{n+1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1}csc^2\left(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)
\end{equation}

Completing the proof by induction that equality below is true:

\begin{equation}
    1=\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}} \tag{4}
\end{equation}

On the other hand, using that $\displaystyle csc^2x=cot^2x+1$, we get:

\begin{equation}
    1=\frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}cot^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}+\frac{2^{n}}{4^n}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}cot^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}=1-\frac{1}{2^n} \tag{5}
\end{equation}

Using that $\displaystyle senx\leq x \leq tanx \Rightarrow cotx\leq \frac{1}{x} \leq cscx \Rightarrow cot^2x\leq \frac{1}{x^2} \leq csc^2x$, we have:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}cot^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}\leq \frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\frac{2^{2n+2}}{((2k+1)\pi)^2} \leq \frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}cot^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}}\leq \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\frac{8}{((2k+1)\pi)^2} \leq \frac{2}{4^n}\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}csc^2\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2^{n+1}} \tag{6}
\end{equation}

Substituting ( 4) and (5 ) in (6 ) , we have:

\begin{equation}
    1-\frac{1}{2^n}\leq \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\frac{8}{((2k+1)\pi)^2} \leq 1
\end{equation}
Taking limit to infinity in all parts of inequality , we have:

\begin{equation}
    \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^n}\right)\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}-1}\frac{8}{((2k+1)\pi)^2} \leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 1
\end{equation}

Hence:
\begin{equation}
     \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} =\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{equation}
Observe that:

\begin{equation*}
     \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k^2}= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+...+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+...+\frac{1}{4^n}\right)\frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
     = \frac{1}{3}\frac{\pi^2}{8}\Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}
\end{equation}
It follows that:

\begin{equation}
     \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}
\end{equation}

Comment: How is this a Complex Analysis Solution ?

Answer (score 3):

Although there are so many different contour integrals to use as evidenced by the different posts to this question and other similar questions, here is a neat one I used. Consider the integral:
$$\int_C \frac{\frac{1}{z^2}}{e^{i \pi z}+1} dz
$$
Where C traverses through a square whose diagonals intersect at the origin in the complex plane and whose side lengths are 2N, where N is a very large even number. It can be shown through parametrizing the sides of the square and using the estimation lemma that this integral along C vanishes for very large 2N.  Now, we need to calculate the residues of every pole. Let 
$$
f(z)=\frac{\frac{1}{z^2}}{e^{i \pi z}+1}
$$ 
We see there are first order poles at $z=\pm (2n-1) $ for all positive integers n. There is also a second order pole at z=0.
We will calculate the residues for the first order poles. Let a be an odd integer 
$$
Res (f(z),a)=\lim \limits_{z \to a} {(z-a)f(z)}= \frac{i}{\pi a^2}
$$
For the second order pole at z=0:
$$
Res (f(z),0)=\lim \limits_{z \to 0} \frac{d}{dz} (z^2f(z))=\frac{-\pi i}{4}
$$
We now utilize Cauchy's residue theorem, which states:
$$
\int_C g(z) dz= 2\pi i\sum{Res(g(z))} 
$$
if the singularities of $ g(z) $ are located in the interior of C.
In our case, 
$$
\int_C \frac{\frac{1}{z^2}}{e^{i \pi z}+1} dz= 2 \pi i (\frac{-\pi i}{4}) + 2 \pi i \sum_{n=0}^
\infty\frac{2i}{\pi (2n+1)^2}
$$
The $"2"$ inside the summation accounts for the fact that the residue of a particular negative odd integer for $ f(z)$ is equivalent to the residue of its positive counterpart. We also know the left hand side, from what was established earlier, equals $0$. Thus,
$$
0= 2 \pi i (\frac{-\pi i}{4}) + 2 \pi i \sum_{n=0}^
\infty\frac{2i}{\pi (2n+1)^2}
$$
Dividing both sides by $2 \pi i$ and adding $\frac{\pi i}{4}$ to both sides, we see:
$$
\frac{\pi i}{4}=\sum_{n=0}^
\infty\frac{2i}{\pi (2n+1)^2} 
$$
Now, multiplying both sides by $\frac{\pi}{2i}$, we get the result:
$$
\frac {\pi^2}{8}= \sum_{n=0}^
\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2} 
$$

Rearranging the terms from the $ \sum_{n=1}^
\infty\frac{1}{n^2} $, we can extrapolate that 
$$
\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^
\infty\frac{1}{n^2}= \sum_{n=0}^
\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}
$$
Thus, we see:
$$\sum_{n=1}^
\infty\frac{1}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}
$$
As a fun fact, you can get more zeta values considering the contour integral:
$$\int_C \frac{\frac{1}{z^{2n}}}{e^{i \pi z}+1} dz
$$
where n is a positive integer and C is the same contour as used before.